# Can Cauchy's Theorem be used to solve a contour integral with singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I am having trouble trying to solve the following contour integral for an assignment:
$\oint_C \left(z + \frac{1}{z^2}\right) \, dz$
where $C$ is the contour defined by $|z| = 2$. My professor is known for assigning tricky problems, and I wonder if this is one of them, as we have been specifically asked to use Cauchy's Theorem to solve it.

I know that typically Cauchy's Theorem is applied to analytic functions without singularities inside the contour of integration. However, the function  $f(z) = z + \frac{1}{z^2}$ clearly has singularities at $z = 0$.

I have reviewed my notes and understand that the Cauchy Integral Formula is a common way to solve such integrals when there are singularities. However, I would like to clarify that I am specifically exploring whether there is a way to use Cauchy's Theorem for this exercise.

I appreciate in advance any help or advice you can provide. If you need more details about the exercise or any further clarification, please let me know.

Comment: Would be useful if you stated the exact version of Cauchy's theorem that you are talking about.

Comment: You can use Cauchy's integral formula for first derivative

Comment: Cauchy's theorem cannot be applied here because of the singular term $1/z^2$. Nevertheless, in the case where you are referring to Cauchy's residue formula instead, then you'll find that the residue of the said second term is zero. Alternatively, you may compute this integral explicitly thanks to the change of variable $z = 2e^{it}$, with $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @MorA. My professor did not specify the exact version of Cauchy's theorem in the given context. However, based on what we have covered in class and the nature of the problem, I assume the reference is to the Cauchy-Goursat theorem.

Comment: using linearity you can write this as $\oint_C z \,dz  +\oint_C\frac{1}{z^2}\, dz$ where the former is zero by Cauchy's Theorem; and supposing you know the  homologous version of said theorem then you also know $\oint_C\frac{1}{z^2}\, dz= \oint_{C'}\frac{1}{z^2}\, dz$ where $C'$ is the contour defined with radius $r$, where $r$ may be chosen to be arbitrarily large, hence the integral is zero via ML Inequality.

Answer (score 2):

No, Cauchy's first integral theorem cannot be used directly here. It states that if $U$ is a simply connected domain, and $C$ is a closed curve in $U$ and $f$ is holomorphic on $U$, then $$\int_C fdz=0.$$ $C$ is obviously closed and $f$ is holomorphic on $C$ but we need to choose $U$. The problem is that we cannot choose $U$ to be simply connected without including $0$. However if we include $0$ then $f$ is not holomorphic on all of $U$.

In this case $f$ has a primitive on an open set containing the curve. In particular $$F(z)=\frac{z^2}2-\frac1z.$$ We can thus evaluate the integral as $$F(C(1))-F(C(0))=F(2)-F(2)=0$$ if we assume that $C$ starts and ends at the point $2$.